# Explicit variable declaration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, syntax, variable-declaration

I have a local variable implicitly defined as `var`, and is being populated with objects retrieved from a database through entity framework. When I hover over the variable I get the details as shown in the image below.

[image]

How can I explicitly define my variable without using var, for example

```
IQuerable<{Inpection Ins, Field F}> tempInspInner =  getInspections();
```

Instead of:

```
var tempInspInner =  getInspections();
```

---

**UPDATE**

getInspections() has the following code:

```
return _dbcontext.Inspection
                .Join(_dbcontext.Field,
                ins => ins.FieldId,
                f => f.FieldId,
                (ins, f) => new { Ins = ins, F = f }).Where(*hidden*);
```

Comment: `How can I explicitly define my variable without using var, for example` If it is an anonymous type, you can't. You need to use `var`.

Comment: It's anonymous in the sense that you can't explicitly declare an instance of it. You don't have code that defines `class Result { public Inspection Ins {get; set;} public Field F {get; set;} }`. The compiler can figure this out and likely creates the type in the background, but it's anonymous. You could create your own type that contains the fields you want to return from your query, and then return an `IQueryable` of *that* type (i.e. `=> new Result { Ins = ins, F = f }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getInspections` returns an anonymous type (meh *sigh*), named tuples wont help, however you could project it to a class

```
public class SomeObject 
{
    public Inpection Ins {get;set;}
    public Field F {get;set;}
}

IQueryable<SomeObject> = getInspections.Select(x => new SomeObject { Ins = x.Ins, F = x.F });
```

On saying this, you probably be better return the a strongly typed `IQueryable` anyway

Comment: Ive add the code within GetInspections(). Does this answer work with that?

Comment: @pnizzle yes it does

Comment: Fyi, if `getInspections()` returns `IQueryable<object>` then this still won't work since you don't know the properties available on the anonymous type returned from the method.

Comment: I did do this. But I ended up finding it redundant after refactoring my code (nothing to do with your answer). Ive leant from this, and for that today was a good day.

Comment: @TheGeneral with the creation of new SomeObject with the values of x, will that load up the objects of the result of getInspections(), thereby cancelling out lazy loading (which from my understanding comes as default with entity framework)?

Comment: No. Since `Select` still returns an `IQueryable` and does not enumerate the results, the query is not executed. It just projects the results into the specified form, which will then be translated into the query once the results are enumerated.

Comment: @MichaelRandall what is a strongly typed IQuerable, in this case?

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the ideal option would be to have `getInspections()` return a strongly typed collection.

As an alternative, you should be able to define your variable with an explicit type (using [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples)) as follows:

```
IEnumerable<(Inspection Ins, Field F)> test = getInspections()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Cast<dynamic>()
    .Select(x => (Ins: (Inspection)x.Ins, F: (Field)x.F));
```

One downside to this approach is that since the results are being cast to `dynamic`, the compiler won't know if the source properties being used (`x.Ins` and `x.F`) ever change. So you won't know that this doesn't work until it is executed at runtime.

Comment: the thing is, I need to pass the object from getInspections() (lets call that inspections) to another method that will iterate though the contents and create new objects. If I do not specify how the contents of inspections is structured, then that method won't know how to iterate it through the select function. unless I am missing something here.

Comment: In the example I gave, if you need to pass `test` into another method, the parameter of that method would just have to be defined as `IEnumerable<(Inspection Ins, Field F)>`

Comment: is the cast necessary?  `Cast<dynamic>()`  ?